# How to install MySQL?

Tags: software-installation, mysql

I tried running `mysql` in my terminal and I got:

```
The program 'mysql' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

But when I do:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-client-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
```

Running `ls -l /usr/bin/mysql` returns:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-client-core-5.5`

Answer (score 97):

First, remove the current version of MySQL you're already using:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.5
```

Now, to install MySQL, run the following command from a terminal prompt:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

During the installation process you will be prompted to enter a password for the MySQL root user.

Once the installation is complete, the MySQL server should be started automatically. You can run the following command from a terminal prompt to check whether the MySQL server is running:

```
$sudo ss -tlp | grep mysql
```

When you run this command, you should see the following line or something similar:

```
LISTEN 0      80                 *:mysql            *:*    users:(("mysqld",pid=898368,fd=20))
```

If the server is not running correctly, you can type the following command to start it:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

You can edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file to configure the basic settings: log file, port number, etc.

Answer (score 23):

This command installs the MySQL server, which you need.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If you want to run commands from the workbench and not from a terminal, you need the client as well (this is optional):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

For MySQL Workbench (also optional):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score 10):

First you have to remove MySQL completely from your system using following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Now try to reinstall MySQL.

Answer (score 9):

That suggestion seems a little bizzare because it would miss out other dependencies and utilities. I would just run this and be done with it:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```