# Unable to reinstall mysql on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, reinstall

Linux newb, so please be gentle.

Tried to start mysql using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and I got the following error:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Online solutions suggested that I should reinstall mysql, so that's what I did, except now I'm getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 5.6.23-1ubuntu14.10) but it is not going to be installed
```

Had no luck so far. Apologises if the question is stupid. I've already tried everything suggested in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174138/how-to-install-mysql) as well as many other places but to no avail.

Cheers.

List of installed packages:

```
akonadi-backend-mysql               deinstall
libmysqlcppconn7                deinstall
mysql-apt-config                install
mysql-server-5.5                deinstall
mysql-workbench                 deinstall
```

No error log, I think it got deleted when I attempted to do a deep complete removal.

Comment: You may get a better response from [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: To help further please upload the MySQL error log if it exists (/var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.err) and also the list of installed packages, (dpkg --get-selections|grep -i mysql)

Comment: Original post updated. Thanks for looking into this, it's driving me insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `mysql-apt-config` (which is in development and might not be resolving the dependencies correctly) and to reinstall `mysql-server` from the official repositories:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-apt-config && sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no more needed.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

Now reinstall MySQL

### Install Mysql 5.7

#### Install Mysql

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
mysql_secure_installation
```

#### Check is Mysql process running

```
sudo service mysql status
```

#### Setup enable remote access (Use Vim, nano, the text editor you prefer...)

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

Edit conf

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1 --> bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Add permission to user

[How to create a user and grant permissions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql)

Grant also for root

```
grant all privileges on *.* to root@'%' identified by <PASSWORD>;
flush privileges;
```