# Problem when making a file excutable

Tags: permissions

OS Ubuntu 22.04
posper 3.0-1390-6.851-09.02.2023.tar.gz

I downloaded and unzipped the archive to `/opt/posper` following instructions on `readme.txt`.

> On property of posper.exe  and on config.exe change to Allow executing file as program

I tried the GUI method, but it gave the following error message:

> An error occurred while loading the archive.

I also tried with Terminal, but it was not successful either.

```
luis@l-System-luisj:/opt/posper$ sudo chmod +rw-rx-r-- /opt/posper/posper.exe
luis@l-System-luisj:/opt/posper$ sudo ./posper.exe
sudo: ./posper.exe: command not found
luis@l-System-luisj:/opt/posper$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to run a Windows application on Linux. Find a Linux version, or use wine.

Comment: Judging from [this discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/posper/discussion/606132/thread/81b0db16d7/?limit=25#a70e) POSper does indeed run on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You are copying the wrong file, and extracting it with the wrong command. The normal `unzip` marks the permissions as executable as expected. Here is a working installation procedure:

1. Download "posper-3.0-1390-6.851-09.02.2023.zip" from https://sourceforge.net/projects/posper/files/POSper%20Releases/3.0/
2. `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre` to Install Java 8 (newer won't work with the config program)
3. `rm -rf ~/posper*` to clean up the old POSper install
4. `sudo rm -rf /opt/posper`
5. `sudo unzip -d /opt posper-3.0-1390-6.851-09.02.2023.zip` This should extract things with the proper permissions
6. `sudo mv /opt/posper-3.0-1390-6.851-09.02.2023 /opt/posper`
7. `sudo chmod 755 /opt/posper/{config,newlog,posper,startmenu.{de,en},update}`. This allows running when not root.
8. `echo '#!/bin/true' | sudo tee /opt/posper/update` to neutralize the file that doesn't work
9. `sudo touch /opt/posper/{audit,posper,trace}.log` Create the dummy log files (the real ones are in `~/posper_logs`)
10. `sudo chmod 666 /opt/posper/{audit,posper,trace}.log` Make the dummy log files writable or else POSper will crash
11. Edit `/opt/posper/posper` and `/opt/posper/config` to uncomment and replace the relevant line to look like `JAVAEXEC=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`
12. Install and start a MySQL database. For a Docker example, open another terminal window and run `docker run --rm -it -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=posperdb mysql:5.7.41`. MySQL ≥ 8 won't work. The example is insecure and will delete all data on shutdown, so set up a proper database later
13. Start `/opt/posper/config`
14. Click on the database tab
15. Select `/opt/posper/libs/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar` as the driver library. I used the picker with the folder icon, so make sure that the driver class and URL are updated to MySQL properly
16. Enter "root" as username
17. Enter "test123" as password
18. Press "Save"
19. Press "Exit"
20. Launch `/opt/posper/posper`. It's a graphical application, so you shouldn't use sudo to run it as root. The Windows version is `posper.exe`, so make sure to use the Linux version, which is named just `posper`
21. Click through all the dialogs
22. Click a role to begin

Your `chmod +rw-rx-r--` does not make sense, and it sets the permissions to `--w--w----`. `sudo ./posper.exe` says "command not found" because it is not executable.

The infinite loading cursor when clicking a role is caused by a database error. The builtin HSQL database doesn't work, so we use a MySQL database as `/opt/posper/readme.txt` suggests. If there is a problem, you can look at the logs in `~/posper_logs/posper.log` to debug.

[image: welcome screen]
[image: admin screen]
[image: employee screen]
[image: guest screen]
[image: manager screen]

Comment: Your help it work properly and was a good lesson for me but still a problem don’t
know if it is of your field but there it goes.
Launch posper the main page opens has four buttons “Admin, Employee, Guest and Manager”
on the top right hand About POSper and Close.
Click on “About POSper” opens a window with all information.
Click on any other  button a search well keeps going around and nothing opens.

Comment: @LuisJacinto I found that that is caused by a database connection error. See ~/posper_logs/posper.log. I added to my answer how to set up the MySQL database to get POSper working

Comment: Still some problems.
Line 12.   docker run --rm -it -p 3306:3306,  etc.
Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed 
install # version 3.4.4+ds1-1ubuntu1.22.04.2 
My version is 22.04.3
 
Run line 12 
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
Error: short-name "mysql:5.7.41" did not resolve to an alias and no unqualified-search registries are defined in "/etc/containers/registries.conf"

Run /opt/posper/posper
error:Posper was unable to initialize the connection to the database. Please check to make sure the connection parameters are correct.

Comment: @LuisJacinto I recommend you actually set up MySQL according to your long term plans (such as by following https://askubuntu.com/q/174138/1004020). The example I gave will delete all stored data when the computer is shut down. If you still want to run the example just to get something working quickly, then install the Docker platform by following https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: luis@l-System-luisj:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-client-core-5.5 is not available
This may mean that the package is missing,
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
 mariadb-client-core-10.6
E: Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' has no installation candidate
luis@l-System-luisj:~$  mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
luis@l-System-luisj:~$

Comment: @LuisJacinto It appears the required MySQL version ≤ 5 is no longer available in the Ubuntu repositories. You can just install Docker and use the command I provided for Docker. Once you're ready for the long term data storage, read the "Where to Store Data" and the "*_PASSWORD" sections of https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: While installing Docker .deb package this error come up “Docker error while installation "Unable to install docker-desktop :  the following packages have unmet dependencies".

Comment: It is never recommended on Ubuntu to install .deb packages. Follow the official instructions at https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: Eventually I got docker installed.
Following you instruction for installation on line 11. 
“to uncomment and replace the relevant line to look like”
Need help on this where or what line number to insert the command?

Comment: @LuisJacinto If you only have one version of Java (Java 8 is most likely to work) installed, you can skip that step